# string literal is not properly closed by a matching quote

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling getting rid of the error on line 2.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot your source code :-)

Comment: I see, the image is blocked by my local contentfilter

Comment: It'd be nice if it were actual *text*.  :P  WTF is this an image for?

Comment: this was pretty funny, indeed, but please, don't share any code by image next time. ^_^

Comment: Post the code, not an image. An image of the code isn't helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the first new line character (after the opening double quote):

```
$("#insert-rated-category"+voteit).html(" \
    <select id='' name=''> \
        <option value=''></option> \
    </select> \
");
```

**Edit**

You'll have to escape the new line character in blank lines too. Thanks @cHao.

Comment: I imagine you have to make sure to escape the newlines at the end of the empty lines as well.